# Are there any antigen electronic sensors?

Tags: immunology, antibody, antigen

Is it possible somehow to attach antibody to silicon or to other electronic component chemical, and have electronic detector of correspondent antigen?

Does such devices exist?

Comment: Try Googling "antibody biosensor" to get started.